# TDS Code Generation - What options do I have to run this away from the IDE?

Tags: tds, helix

We are able to run the code generation through the Visual Studio IDE (Right click -> Regenerate for all items)

Are there other options available, such as Project Build targets or an external program that can be run?

The reason for this is that we have (or will have) many projects within a Helix / Habitat style architecture, and would like to run all the code generation at certain times.

Comment: You're probably wanting to use something like this: http://hermanussen.eu/sitecore/wordpress/2015/04/generating-sitecore-code-without-tds/

Comment: When running code gen 'at certain times', does that necessarily have to be at build time outside of the IDE? Or would a feature request for 'Re-Generate all generated code in the solution' still from within the IDE be helpful?

Comment: When you say code generation, do you mean deploy? I would think code generation occurs during development of a discreet Module.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby A "regenerate all code in the solution" would be helpful, yes.
The main point is that I'd rather have the GeneratedCode.cs (or whatever the file name is) to not be checked in, and to generate on the build server, or locally if there is no regen option

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible.

The explanation is that since MSBuild doesn’t include the T4 processing engine inside its build components, TDS isn’t able to make a call to it during the execution of a build.

This is the main reason why code needs to be generated and checked-in before builds happen.

Comment: I'm sure I have seen the T4 template used with MSBuild before. I will need to look for this somewhere